# Could one obtain an object to destroy a Horcrux in the Room of Requirements?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux

Could one perhaps *require* from the Room of Requirements an object which is powerful enough to destroy a Horcrux?

Let's say you could even be specific, for example: 'I *need* a Basilisk Fang'.

I'm not saying *why* didn't this happen because that would be silly, but **is this possible?**

**EDIT:**

More than just a Basilisk Fang; what about the Sword of Gryffindor (**after** is is imbued with the Basilisk venom)? or any other known destroyers of a Horcrux?

Comment: I suppose that the Room might do some sort of sanitation of requests (e.g. “I want a terrible weapon to destroy the entire castle” would be declined) to ensure your safety, and the safety of the rest of the castle. Since most anti-Horcrux tools are deadly weapons (Basilisk fangs, venom-tinged swords, FiendFyre), I wonder if this might get turned down. Just a thought.

Comment: Further, can the room actually be used just to produce stuff? If it could, we'd perhaps have: "I need a five-foot long essay for Professor Snape on Amortentia." Maybe the room can be used only to, uh, transform itself into a room which would satisfy the needs of the person. Like the DA asked for a room to practice DADA, so that's what they got. There *is* a mention of Dobby finding antidotes and a bed, but he may have asked for a nursing room for a wounded elf. Just a thought. :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends.

The room seems to operate under Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration.

So, **if Basilisk fangs are part of one of the Five Exceptions to it** (we only really know one exception from canon - food), they wouldn't be possible to obtain; otherwise they should be possible.

Comment: Basilisk fangs are body parts of a living being and living beings can generally be used as food. Maybe this argument support the applicability of Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration.

Comment: @Philipp Mar: What if you simply asked for "**a vial of Basilisk venom**"? It _might_ be able to get around "no body parts/food(-like) items" exception. We know that Filch occasionally found some cleaning products when he needed them (OotP,Ch18) and that Dobby found some "butterbeer antidotes" (same chapter) so certain (non-edible) substances might be feasible.

Comment: @DVK - Basilisk fangs are just 1 example. It is not _the only thing_ that can destroy a horcrux. The room can generate inanimate objects. The sword of Godric Gryffindor was an inanimate object. I think the question also covers such objects.

Comment: @Philipp can you use a basilisk fang as food? I don't think so... therefore, if Basilisk fangs are part of one of the Five Exceptions, they can only be part of one of the other four exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

I'd imagine it falls under the [Law of Elemental Transfiguration](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp%27s_Law_of_Elemental_Transfiguration). The Room of Requirement is subject to this law (cannot summon food) and there are four other categories of non-transfigurable/summonable items not explicitly mentioned in the books, which may include Basilisk fangs in some way. I'd imagine "body parts" is a reasonable candidate for one of the other categories.

Comment: "Which may include" and "I'd imagine" are generally not found in a good answer. Those phrases are indicative of opinion and conjecture. (Not downvoting or voting to close, just a comment.)

Comment: I guess this would be a tricky question to answer without some amount of conjecture.